# CRM Online SOAP Endpoint

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm

I had a requirement to connect CRM Online to a Drupal website.  As I didn't have the benefit of writing a custom web service so I used the CRM SOAP interface and PHP.

This was working fine for months however in the last week and a bit this has stopped working.  I can retrieve the required tokens for authentication however any request I send off results in a blank response.

Has anyone else come across this or can point me in the best direction to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer.

The following is a snapshot of my code

```
$cURLHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $soapUrl);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
$response = curl_exec($cURLHandle);
curl_close($cURLHandle);
```

Two things I need to be fixed here.  Firstly I was doing nothing when there was an issue here where I really should be replacing this line

```
$response = curl_exec($cURLHandle);
```

With this

```
if( ! $response = curl_exec($cURLHandle)) 
{ 
    trigger_error(curl_error($cURLHandle)); 
}
```

And secondly it appears the SSL version being used has been modified.  By changing this line

```
curl_setopt($cURLHandle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

To version 4 instead of 3 it started working!  So instead of this i've just commented out this line entirely.

Hope this helps someone else!